# read file using read_table /read_csv command

Tags: pandas, csv, text

i have text file which contains following information

```
# Column1 Column2
10  12
15  7
20  9
30  11
40  20
60  25
```

i have tried to read  this file  like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file =pd.read_table("results.txt",sep="\t")
print(file.head())
```

result is this :

```
   # Column1 Column2
10                 12
15                  7
20                  9
30                 11
40                 20
```

of course  i can use skiprows  to skip first rows like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file =pd.read_table("results.txt",sep="\t",skiprows=1,header=None)
print(file.head())
```

result is :

```
   0   1
0  10  12
1  15   7
2  20   9
3  30  11
4  40  20
```

but i want to keep original columns, how to do it? How to separate columns  well?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

Read in your data using `read_csv` use the `Sep=" "` so as to use spaces.

Input is messy so a little cleanup. Drop the unwanted column1 which will be full of NAs. Then rename the column holding the data you want to call column1.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r"results.txt", sep=" ")

data.drop('Column1', inplace=True, axis=1)
data.rename(columns={'#': 'Column1'}, inplace=True)
print(data)
```

output

```
   Column1  Column2
0       10       12
1       15        7
2       20        9
3       30       11
4       40       20
5       60       25
```

Comment: no  it does not solve the problem, here issue is that Column1 and Column  two and # sign are just one text

Comment: Looks to me that there are spaces between ```# Column1 Column2``` so that should work.

Comment: how can i show file?

Comment: You mean how can you see the data once in the dataframe? You can print the df. ```print(data)```

Comment: no no, how can i share the file in order to see exact form, is there possibility?

Comment: You could copy paste some of the values from the file in to your question. Are you saying the way the data is shown in your question is not how your data is really formatted?

Comment: The solution is working for the way you presented the data in your question. If your real dataset (txt file) is not presented in the same way then you need to change the data in the question.